# Best way to do search of an item in list

Tags: list, linq

I am new to collections and linq and was wondering what would be a better way to do a search on the list for this part of the code which does O(n) operation, where n is Count. Dont want O(n) rather O(1)
    (MapList.Find()).

I am open to suggestions or even changing it if there is a better solution.

```
List<Mapp> MapList = dtResults.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new Mapp()
                {
                    Key = (int)r["Key"],
                    AlternateId = (string)r["AlternateId"],
                }).ToList();

oValueRow["Key"] = MapList.Find(x => x.AlternateId == 
Names.ElementAt(n).ToString()).Key;
```

Is there a way to make it better in a way that MapList can find do O(1) operation rather than O(N). I cant do Elementat (n) on maplist as I need only the element where x = alternateId.

Answer (score 0):

If AlternateId is not guaranteed to be unique, [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) (multiple values per key) can be used :

```
var lookup = dtResults.AsEnumerable()
                      .ToLookup(r => r["AlternateId"]?.ToString() ?? "", r => (int)r["Key"]);

oValueRow["Key"] = lookup[Names.ElementAt(n).ToString()].FirstOrDefault();
```

---

If AlternateId is guaranteed to be unique, [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) (single value per key) can be used :

```
var dictionary = dtResults.AsEnumerable()
                  .ToDictionary(r => r["AlternateId"]?.ToString() ?? "", r => (int)r["Key"]);

int key;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(Names.ElementAt(n).ToString(), out key))
    oValueRow["Key"] = key;
```

Comment: Thanks Slai, actually Key is unique, alternateId can be unique but it can have null values too. I am trying to do something like this but cant get the if code to work.  var dictionary = dtResults.AsEnumerable()
                          .ToDictionary(r =>(int)r["Key"], r => (string)r["alternateId"]);   and I need the Key value based on the alternateId provided.  int Key;
                        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(stInfo.name, out Key)

Comment: @Sarah the value that is used to search by (alternateId) should be first as shown in my examples. Try the first example if you can't figure out the second one.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. Yes I tried making alternateId as the first argument but because dtresults can have null value in alternateId field, it doesnt like it. How can I only pick records from dtResults that are not null, then I can do what you are recomending.